# accessing character pointer

Tags: c++

In C++, why compilers do not allows to modify the following character pointer as following

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
char* cp = "overflow";
cp[1]='p';
return 0;
}
```

Output : crashes at runtime.

but character array allows,

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
char cps[] = "overflow";
cp[1]='p'; // this compiles fine and output is operflow
return 0;
}
```

just want to know what is happening at runtime and why it is crashing. Thank you.

Comment: `char cps = "overflow";` is just wrong, did you mean `char cps[] = "overflow";`?

Comment: @unwind sorry, somehow it went missing. corrected..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String literals are lvalues of type `char const[]`, where the `const` is the important part. Trying to modify an object whose type is `const` is **Undefined Behavior**.

Per Paragraph 2.14.5/8 of the C++11 Standard:

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. **A narrow
>   string literal has type “array of *n* `const char`”**, where *n* is the size of the string as defined below, and has
>   static storage duration (3.7).

In the second case (supposing your meant `char cps[] = "overflow";`, with square brackets), you are initializing a non-`const` *copy* of the string literal. Modifying that copy is OK.

Also notice, that the conversion from a string literal to non`-const` `char *` is deprecated in C++03 and **illegal** in C++11. This, on the other hand, is legal:

```
char const* cp = "overflow";
//   ^^^^^
```

Comment: There should be at least a warning, surely, on most compilers, even pre-C++11?

Comment: @drquicksilver: There is on GCC, provided that you raise the warning level up enough.

Comment: @ Andy, why it is treated as char const[], any valid reason behind it?

Comment: @drquicksilver  yup, i got compiler warning "deprecated version from string constant to char*"

Comment: @UmalStack: That is what the Standard mandates, and the reason probably has to do with the fact that string literals (well, all literals) are meant to be immutable values

Comment: Keeping it `const` allows the compiler to allow duplicates of the values to be merged into one, so if you do `char *p = "blah"; ... char *q = "blah";`, there need to be only one copy of `"blah"` in the binary file. If you can modify the string, then each initializer would have to be its own unique string, as if you then did `p[1] = 'e';`, you wouldn't want `cout << q << endl;` to print "bleh", right?

Comment: Yes, and the amount of space saved by storing "%25s" or other arguments to for example printf is often quite a lot, because there tends to be quite a few different places that the same format string is used. Typically, strings are only packed from one compile unit, but I believe for example MS compilers have a final step that basically goes through and compacts ALL matching strings into one string of each.

Answer (score 2):

This: `char* str="";`, is a string literal and may be stored in read only section of memory hence may crash. Use `const char* const str="string";` (both the pointer and data are constant OR atleast the data should be constant: `const char* str="string";` or `char const* str="string";`)

If you try to change the the contents of a string literal it is undefined behavior and segmentation fault resulting in crash can happen.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `char* cp = "overflow";` you are creating a read-only block of memory containing `"overflow"` (followed by a NULL terminating byte), so you cannot write there. Trying to change `c[x]` requires writing there.

As to your second block of code -- something is missing so that part of the question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Because a pointer to character is not an `array` and a `low-level const`. You could do

```
char cp[] = {'o', 'v', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'l', 'o', 'w', '\0'};

char *pcp = cp;

*++pcp = 'p';
```

However, `"overflow"` is a constant sequence of characters that is not modifiable, Hence you can only perform pointer arithmetic and dereference the pointer for a value.

```
char *cp = "overflow";

std::cout << *++cp std::endl;
```